# how to make hiding header and footer on content scroll in ionic3

Tags: javascript, html, ionic3, footer

It is very common now a days to make header and footer hide & show on scrolling the page and here is the solution if we have ionic info as-

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v8.1.0
    npm  : 5.3.0 
    OS   : Linux 4.4
```

**Create a file in provider with name *scroll* and add a file as `scroll-hide.ts`** in it as-

```
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
    selector: '[scrollHide]'
})
export class ScrollHideDirective {

    @Input('scrollHide') config: ScrollHideConfig;
    @Input('scrollContent') scrollContent: Content;

    contentHeight: number;
    scrollHeight: number;
    lastScrollPosition: number;
    lastValue: number = 0;

    constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (this.scrollContent && this.config) {
            this.scrollContent.ionScrollStart.subscribe((ev) => {
                this.contentHeight = this.scrollContent.getScrollElement().offsetHeight;
                this.scrollHeight = this.scrollContent.getScrollElement().scrollHeight;
                if (this.config.maxValue === undefined) {
                    this.config.maxValue = this.element.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
                }
                this.lastScrollPosition = ev.scrollTop;
            });
            this.scrollContent.ionScroll.subscribe((ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));
            this.scrollContent.ionScrollEnd.subscribe((ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));
        }
    }

    private adjustElementOnScroll(ev) {
        if (ev) {
            ev.domWrite(() => {
                let scrollTop: number = ev.scrollTop > 0 ? ev.scrollTop : 0;
                let scrolldiff: number = scrollTop - this.lastScrollPosition;
                this.lastScrollPosition = scrollTop;
                let newValue = this.lastValue + scrolldiff;
                newValue = Math.max(0, Math.min(newValue, this.config.maxValue));
                this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, this.config.cssProperty, `-${newValue}px`);
                this.lastValue = newValue;
            });
        }
    }
}
export interface ScrollHideConfig {
    cssProperty: string;
    maxValue: number;
}
```

**Now we need to declare it in your app module inside `app.module.ts-`**
and add-

```
import { ScrollHideDirective } from '../providers/scroll/scroll-hide';
```

at top of the page, now it's time to include in @NgModule section as-

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    ScrollHideDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {})
  ],

providers: [
   ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Move to the page `(home.ts)` where we want hide-show footer and header, add the following-

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ScrollHideConfig } from '../../directives/scroll-hide';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-explore',
  templateUrl: 'explore.html'
})
export class ExplorePage {

  footerScrollConfig: ScrollHideConfig = { cssProperty: 'margin-bottom', maxValue: undefined };
  headerScrollConfig: ScrollHideConfig = { cssProperty: 'margin-top', maxValue: 44 };

  ...

}
```

Now we have to implement the same in view page `(home.html)`

```
<ion-header [scrollHide]="headerScrollConfig" [scrollContent]="pageContent">
  ...
</ion-header>

<ion-content #pageContent fullscreen>
  ...
</ion-content>

<ion-footer [scrollHide]="footerScrollConfig" [scrollContent]="pageContent">
  ...
</ion-footer>
```

That all to make our task done.
Have a good day ahead!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question, but a solution to a problem posted as question.

Comment: Questions can be self-answered on Stack Overflow, but they have to follow the question/answer format. Please change your post so that you ask an on-topic question above. You can then post this answer in the answer box.

Comment: I don't know how to make so, better if you can help me about.

Comment: You can use your complete question text as answer, so you can copy and paste it into the answer box and add the link from your current answer as well. The tricky part is to post a good question that fits the answer. If you encountered the problem yourself, you could ask how to solve it and show the approach that failed.

Comment: Just have a look on it.

Comment: The answer looks fine now. All that's missing is a question posted above that would lead to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It is very common now a days to make header and footer hide & show on scrolling the page and here is the solution if we have ionic info as-

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v8.1.0
    npm  : 5.3.0 
    OS   : Linux 4.4
```

**Create a file in provider with name *scroll* and add a file as `scroll-hide.ts`** in it as-

```
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
    selector: '[scrollHide]'
})
export class ScrollHideDirective {

    @Input('scrollHide') config: ScrollHideConfig;
    @Input('scrollContent') scrollContent: Content;

    contentHeight: number;
    scrollHeight: number;
    lastScrollPosition: number;
    lastValue: number = 0;

    constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (this.scrollContent && this.config) {
            this.scrollContent.ionScrollStart.subscribe((ev) => {
                this.contentHeight = this.scrollContent.getScrollElement().offsetHeight;
                this.scrollHeight = this.scrollContent.getScrollElement().scrollHeight;
                if (this.config.maxValue === undefined) {
                    this.config.maxValue = this.element.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
                }
                this.lastScrollPosition = ev.scrollTop;
            });
            this.scrollContent.ionScroll.subscribe((ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));
            this.scrollContent.ionScrollEnd.subscribe((ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));
        }
    }

    private adjustElementOnScroll(ev) {
        if (ev) {
            ev.domWrite(() => {
                let scrollTop: number = ev.scrollTop > 0 ? ev.scrollTop : 0;
                let scrolldiff: number = scrollTop - this.lastScrollPosition;
                this.lastScrollPosition = scrollTop;
                let newValue = this.lastValue + scrolldiff;
                newValue = Math.max(0, Math.min(newValue, this.config.maxValue));
                this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, this.config.cssProperty, `-${newValue}px`);
                this.lastValue = newValue;
            });
        }
    }
}
export interface ScrollHideConfig {
    cssProperty: string;
    maxValue: number;
}
```

**Now we need to declare it in your app module inside `app.module.ts-`**
and add-

```
import { ScrollHideDirective } from '../providers/scroll/scroll-hide';
```

at top of the page, now it's time to include in @NgModule section as-

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    ScrollHideDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {})
  ],

providers: [
   ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Move to the page `(home.ts)` where we want hide-show footer and header, add the following-

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ScrollHideConfig } from '../../directives/scroll-hide';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-explore',
  templateUrl: 'explore.html'
})
export class ExplorePage {

  footerScrollConfig: ScrollHideConfig = { cssProperty: 'margin-bottom', maxValue: undefined };
  headerScrollConfig: ScrollHideConfig = { cssProperty: 'margin-top', maxValue: 44 };

  ...

}
```

Now we have to implement the same in view page `(home.html)`

```
<ion-header [scrollHide]="headerScrollConfig" [scrollContent]="pageContent">
  ...
</ion-header>

<ion-content #pageContent fullscreen>
  ...
</ion-content>

<ion-footer [scrollHide]="footerScrollConfig" [scrollContent]="pageContent">
  ...
</ion-footer>
```

That all to make our task done.
Have a good day ahead!!!
Reference solution is available https://medium.com/@gregor.srdic/ionic3-hidding-header-on-footer-on-content-scroll-15ab95b05dc5 @@